# Why would a folder suddenly be inaccessable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am working on a project a logical folder hierarchy. A "borrower" folder, a "lender" folder and an "admin" folder. Suddenly this morning I cannot access any pages in the admin folder. I instantly get redirected to the login page defined in web.config. A breakpoit set in the page_load of the landing page within the admin folder is never hit. It's like the admin folder is locked...  I created a "test.aspx" page and copied it into each folder. I can access (run) the test page in an any folder but the admin folder...

I've never encountered anything like this before. Any suggestions?

Comment: No error. Just can't get any page within the folder to load in the browser.

Comment: Is authentication setup on the admin folder? If it directs you back to the login page it probably is so have you tried actually logging in?

Comment: Neither my team lead or myself is familiar with authentication on a folder... but yes, logged in, session variable set etc. How do I check/set/enable/disable authentication on a folder?

Comment: The test page is basic aspx with no code behind added. I should be able to access it with no permissions of any kind. So "folder authentication" sounds right. But we are unfamiliar...

Comment: Check your Web.Config see if you can see a tag like this <authorization> in it - if so edit your question and post what you have

Comment: Ended up just creating a new folder, copying the contents of the admin folder into it, deleting the admin folder from the solution, then renaming the new folder admin. Everything went back to working... Still don't know how authentication was set on the folder... But simple "hack" method worked to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the folder permissions from the administrator,

verifies that you have access to reading and writing.

see if the folder is shared and reviewed these permits also